# Best approach for Cassandra Partitioning

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I am very new to Cassandra, I have worked with Oracle SQL and Mongo DB and I am trying to learn Apache Cassandra to use it in a project I am working on.

I have a certain number of sensors (let's say 20), that might increase in the future. They send the data to store every 10 seconds. I am aware of bucketing to deal with this type of situations but wondering which one is better.

```
PRIMARY KEY ((sensor_id, day_month_year), reported_at);

PRIMARY KEY ((sensor_id, month_year), reported_at);
```

I don't know if using *month_year* is too much data for a single partition and on the other hand I think that if I use *day_month_year* it creates too many partitions and it slows reading too much when trying to get data since it has to access multiple partitions.

Which one should I use? If you have other good suggestions or just some explanations for me I'd like to hear them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting my answer here you also asked on https://community.datastax.com/questions/10596/.

Sensor data collected every 10 seconds is equivalent to:

- 6 entries per minute
- 360 entries per hour
- 8,640 entries per day
- 260K entries per month

Depending on what other data you store for each row, it will be difficult to keep the size of each partition to the recommended 100MB. This isn't a hard limit so your partitions can go beyond 100MB but you are trading off performance the larger your partition gets.

On its own, Cassandra isn't ideal for performing analytics queries because it is optimised for OLTP workloads where you are reading one partition for each app request. If you need to do OLAP, you will need to do in Spark for efficiency. Cheers!